# VBA Excel finding difference in time when time format m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: vba, excel

I have some experience in VBA for Excel and at the moment I have 2 sheets with data, that I need to compare and extract data.

Sheet1 looks like:

```
A                        B      C       D       E
06/06/2014 00:01:04     \PLUTUS xxxx    xxxx    DERP.OPERATOR
06/06/2014 00:06:05     \PELEUS xxxx    xxxx    LOL.OPERATOR
06/06/2014 00:11:05     \PLUTUS xxxx    xxxx    DERP.OPERATOR
06/06/2014 00:15:42     \CHARON xxxx    xxxx    SUPEROP-DERP
06/06/2014 00:16:06     \PLUTUS xxxx    xxxx    DERP.OPERATOR
```

Sheet2 looks like:

```
A       B       C        D      E       F               G       H
xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    \castor xxxx    SOLDOP-DERP     xxxx    06/06/2014 03:27:58
xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    \oberon xxxx    BBMOP-DERP      xxxx    06/06/2014 03:30:04
xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    \charon xxxx    SUPEROP-DERP    xxxx    06/06/2014 03:32:55
xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    \peleus xxxx    LOL.OPERATOR    xxxx    06/06/2014 09:55:31
xxxx    xxxx    xxxx    \plutus xxxx    GBSOP-DERP      xxxx    06/06/2014 10:00:22
```

I need to make sure that every Sheet2 E Cell Value get's checked against all Sheet1 F Cell Values.

If it finds a match, then it checks if in that Sheet1 row, Cell B matches the value of Sheet2 Cell D.

If both of these are TRUE then the macro should compare if that rows in Sheet1 Cell A time is more or equal to the time in Sheet2 Cell H but not more that the time in Cell H + 12hours.

If all three statements are true then the time from Sheet1 should get copied to Sheet2 Cell I.

**How do I compare, find the difference in the date and time?**

```
Lrow = 2
Lrow2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get's the number of all sheet1 rows'
Lrow3 = 1
Lrow4 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'number of all Sheet2 rows'

SearchStr = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F" & rownumbers1).Value 
SearchStr2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & rownumbers1).Value
For rownumbers1 = Lrow3 To Lrow4
    For rownumbers = Lrow To Lrow2
        If SearchStr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & rownumbers).Value 
         And 
         SearchStr2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & rownumbers).Value 
         And 
         ***Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H" & rownumbers1).Value =< Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rownumbers).Value < Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H" & rownumbers1).Value + 12 hours***
         Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("I" & rownumbers1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rownumbers).Value
            Next rownumbers1
        Else
            Next rownumbers
        End If
```

Please advise how to do the date and time comparison part! Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H" & rownumbers1).Value =< Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rownumbers).Value < Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H" & rownumbers1).Value + #12:00:00 PM#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any easy way to compare date/times in **VBA** is to convert them into floating point values.  This **UDF** compares two date/times and will return **TRUE** only if the second date/time is greater than or equal to the first, but not more than 12 hours greater than the first:

```
Public Function CompareTimes(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As Boolean
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date, f1 As Double, f2 As Double
    d1 = r1.Value
    d2 = r2.Value
    f1 = CDbl(d1)
    f2 = CDbl(d2)
    CompareTimes = False
    If f2 < f1 Then Exit Function
    If f2 > f1 + 0.5 Then Exit Function
    CompareTimes = True
End Function
```

You would use the **UDF** within a **Sub** like:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    MsgBox CompareTimes(r1, r2)
End Sub
```

Comment: much appreciated, this function does exactlywhat I need! :)

Comment: You can do it in one line like this:

Comment: You can do it in one line like this:
`if CDbl(CDate(r1)) > CDbl(CDate(r2)) then Debug.Print "R1 is > R2" Else Debug.Print "R2 is > R1"`
add a condition for equals if you want.
If you want to know the time portion of a date you can do this:
`Debug.Print "Time portion only is: " & CDbl(CDate(r1)) - CDbl(Int(CDate(r1))`  .  This uses the same concept as Gary's Student.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can't write `If dt1 <= dt2 < dt3 Then...`. Instead you must compare in 2 steps:
`If dt1 <= dt2 And dt2 < dt3 Then...`.
2) Also, you will probably save time and improve clarity by using
`Cell(3,rownum)`instead of
`Range("C" & rownum).value`.
`.Value` is not required here, since it is the default property, and for a 1 cell range, you avoid some calculation/concatenation/conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedbck, will try to follow this!